# What is the difference between MongoDB's updateMany() and repeating updateOne() in terms of performance?

Tags: mongodb

I'm curious about the performance advantages of `updateMany()` over `updateOne()` if there are any.
I'd appreciate an explanation about how `updateMany()` works internally compared to `updateOne()`.

Comment: Ten `updateOne`s will scan the full collection 10 times. `updateMany` only once. So it's roughly `n` times slower to use updateOne.

Answer (score 0):

Update many updates all matching documents. Update one updates the first matching document. If you call update one 10 times with the same condition you might update the same document 10 times depending on the condition.

With that said, obviously, updating all required documents in one round-trip instead of issuing one request per document is significantly more efficient.